# Upgrade mongodb from 4.0 to 4.4 failed to load existing data

Tags: mongodb

I'm running ubuntu 20.04, and getting these logs after I upgraded my mongodb from 4.0 to 4.4.
Here's the log from, /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.564+07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.564+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.575+07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.575+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.576+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":327281,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"nsquare"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.576+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.576+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.576+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.577+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/var/lib/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:54.577+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=7402M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.062+07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4671205, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.062+07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23089,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":4671205,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":1065}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.062+07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23090,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.062+07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"Got signal: 6 (Aborted).\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31431,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"BACKTRACE: {bt}","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"565027A69811","b":"565024DAE000","o":"2CBB811","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.606","s+":"1E1"},{"a":"565027A6AEB9","b":"565024DAE000","o":"2CBCEB9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"29"},{"a":"565027A686A6","b":"565024DAE000","o":"2CBA6A6","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9siginfo_tPv","s+":"66"},{"a":"7F37F87F63C0","b":"7F37F87E1000","o":"153C0","s":"funlockfile","s+":"60"},{"a":"7F37F863518B","b":"7F37F85EF000","o":"4618B","s":"gsignal","s+":"CB"},{"a":"7F37F8614859","b":"7F37F85EF000","o":"25859","s":"abort","s+":"12B"},{"a":"565025CB22F2","b":"565024DAE000","o":"F042F2","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj","s+":"12B"},{"a":"565025999FD1","b":"565024DAE000","o":"BEBFD1","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_.cold.1924","s+":"1C7"},{"a":"565025DB4FBA","b":"565024DAE000","o":"1006FBA","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mmbbbb","s+":"12DA"},{"a":"565025D92F00","b":"565024DAE000","o":"FE4F00","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"120"},{"a":"56502665390E","b":"565024DAE000","o":"18A590E","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"4CE"},{"a":"565025D4F507","b":"565024DAE000","o":"FA1507","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi.isra.1409","s+":"3F7"},{"a":"565025D53590","b":"565024DAE000","o":"FA5590","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"650"},{"a":"565025CC27C9","b":"565024DAE000","o":"F147C9","s":"main","s+":"9"},{"a":"7F37F86160B3","b":"7F37F85EF000","o":"270B3","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"F3"},{"a":"565025D4E9BE","b":"565024DAE000","o":"FA09BE","s":"_start","s+":"2E"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"5.4.0-42-lowlatency","version":"#46-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 10 01:43:58 UTC 2020","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"565024DAE000","elfType":3,"buildId":"77B6A138746C90015067F12B963853BD51DAA5A6"},{"b":"7F37F87E1000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0","elfType":3,"buildId":"775CBBFFF814456660786780B0B3B40096B4C05E"},{"b":"7F37F85EF000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"634252E0C5F8B03957A2E529719D4101699A894A"}]}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565027A69811","b":"565024DAE000","o":"2CBB811","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.606","s+":"1E1"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565027A6AEB9","b":"565024DAE000","o":"2CBCEB9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"29"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565027A686A6","b":"565024DAE000","o":"2CBA6A6","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9siginfo_tPv","s+":"66"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F37F87F63C0","b":"7F37F87E1000","o":"153C0","s":"funlockfile","s+":"60"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F37F863518B","b":"7F37F85EF000","o":"4618B","s":"gsignal","s+":"CB"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F37F8614859","b":"7F37F85EF000","o":"25859","s":"abort","s+":"12B"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565025CB22F2","b":"565024DAE000","o":"F042F2","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj","s+":"12B"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565025999FD1","b":"565024DAE000","o":"BEBFD1","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_.cold.1924","s+":"1C7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565025DB4FBA","b":"565024DAE000","o":"1006FBA","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mmbbbb","s+":"12DA"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565025D92F00","b":"565024DAE000","o":"FE4F00","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"120"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"56502665390E","b":"565024DAE000","o":"18A590E","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"4CE"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565025D4F507","b":"565024DAE000","o":"FA1507","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi.isra.1409","s+":"3F7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565025D53590","b":"565024DAE000","o":"FA5590","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"650"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565025CC27C9","b":"565024DAE000","o":"F147C9","s":"main","s+":"9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F37F86160B3","b":"7F37F85EF000","o":"270B3","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"F3"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.109+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"565025D4E9BE","b":"565024DAE000","o":"FA09BE","s":"_start","s+":"2E"}}}
```

Here's the highlighted line containing the error.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.062+07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4671205, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.062+07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23089,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":4671205,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":1065}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-19T14:56:55.062+07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23090,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support skipping versions.  In order to upgrade from 4.0 to 4.4 you will either need to:

- upgrade from 4.0 to 4.2 first, and then from 4.2 to 4.4
  or
- export all of your data from 4.0, install 4.4, then import the data.